# htacess RewriteRule http://domain/folder/(any searchstring) to redirect to http://domain/folder/index.php?option=$1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to create a rewrite rule in my Apache .htaccess file and the goal is:
http://domain/folder/(any search string) to redirect to http://domain/folder/index.php?option=$1
example:
http://domain/folder/covid to redirect to http://domain/folder/index.php?option=covid

I got this setup in htacess in http://domain/folder, but somehow it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/folder]+)/([^/]+)$ http://domain/folder/index.php?option=$1 [L]
```

The website is hosted on http://domain/folder

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this .htaccess inside `folder/`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php?option=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your htaccess file like as follows. Please keep your htaccess file along side with your folder(named `folder`) and NOT inside folder.

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?option=$1 [L]
```

---

---

OR in case your htaccess is present inside folder `folder` then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?option=$1 [L]
```